# Does SQLCipher supports Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, sqlcipher

Does SQLCipher supports Android Lollipop? As you can see in this [link](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher#compatibility) that it says SQLCipher for Android runs from 2.1 to 4.4. There is no mention of support of Android Lollipop (5.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SQLCipher for Android works on Android 5.x. I will alert Zetitec about their out-of-date info there.

Comment: I'm actually unable to integrate SQL cipher with 5.0 devices. SQLCipher requires ARM assemlies to be placed in libs folder, which is not supported on Lollipop and above : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325140/dalvik-system-pathclassloader-cant-find-jni-on-intel-devices

Comment: @AlexVPerl: I haven't had a problem using the SQLCipher AAR on Android 5.0+. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure-AndroidStudio) ran just fine on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0 when I tried it seconds before posting this comment.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know that it works. Need to review what's wrong w my setup then. Will post my results.

Comment: It ended up being my build config - all is well on Lollipop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Android 2.1 - 6.0 support, you can also [integrate SQLCipher as a Gradle dependency](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-add-sqlcipher-to-your-android-app/). Unfortunately, Zetetic's website still has an Eclipse-jar way described, which is kind of deprecated.